# How do I improve speed when using SUM() on a SQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very basic large transactional database (1.5m transactions).

I want to calculate daily totals for the past 30 days. I start by selecting the past 30 days of transactions, which is quick, then I try to do a SUM(), which is very slow.

`ts` is the timestamp of the transaction, `is_complete` is a 0 or 1 flag

```
SELECT DATE(ts) as date, ts, is_complete, cash_in, cash_out 
FROM transactions t
 WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

This runs quickly (36ms) and returns ~56k transactions.

Now I try to GROUP and SUM the totals.

```
SELECT date, SUM(complete)
FROM (SELECT DATE(ts) as date, ts, is_complete, cash_in, cash_out
      FROM transactions t
      WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
     ) a
GROUP BY date
```

This takes 42 seconds.  Why such a big increase from 36ms to 42 seconds?

Then when I start adding fields to SUM(), it gets slower and slower.

```
SELECT date, SUM(complete), SUM(cash_in + cash_out)
FROM (SELECT DATE(ts) as date, ts, is_complete, cash_in, cash_out
      FROM transactions t 
      WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
     ) a
GROUP BY date
```

This takes 140 seconds.

Should I stop trying to use MySQL SUM() and do the SUM in my local code, after the SQL query?  Or can I improve speed with proper indexing?

I have noticed that the speed of this query grows with table size, even though the subquery (past 30 days) is always a similar size.  The past 30 days is always around 50k transactions, which are being summed, but the query takes much longer when the full table is 1.5m transactions versus 100k transactions.  I don't quite understand why the full table size makes a difference, when I'm only summing the results of the subquery.

Comment: >I have noticed that the speed of this query grows with 
>table size, even though the subquery (past 30 days) is 
>always a similar size. 


If you don't have an index on the `ts` column, the query has to scan the _entire_ table to find your subset. Adding that index is the first thing I'd do.

Comment: Please add the output from Explain Plan for the various queries - particular for the same query being run against different sizes of DB

Comment: By "1.5m transactions", you mean "1.5M _rows_ in a table"?

Answer (score 1):

How long does the query take without a subquery?

```
SELECT DATE(ts) as date, SUM(complete)
FROM transactions t
WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
GROUP BY date;
```

One possibility is that the measurement of 36 ms is measuring the time to the *first* row rather than the time for all the rows.  You are saying that 56k rows are returned -- and 36 ms seems pretty fast to return so many rows.

On the other hand, when you do a `GROUP BY`, all the data has to be returned.  Then the aggregation processing starts.

Now, that explains why an aggregation would be much slower than a query without aggregation.  Adding a `SUM()` though should not significantly affect the processing time.  The time is typically dominated by moving data around rather than adding up numbers.  Perhaps something else is going on on the server or locking the table.